# Krajee date range picker, doesn't work with today date

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2

Enter in http://demos.krajee.com/date-range and search for: `Single date and time picker without range`. Then, clear the default date and try to select today date. Nothing appears. It looks that dont work when select "today" date if there is no previous value in the field.

Is not that a bug? I've googled, but nothing appears about this issue.

So, how can I select the "today" date if previously there is no value in the input field?

Comment: The `Single date and time picker without range` widget works fine for me, just need to click the apply button after selecting the date

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is by desing - if the date is the same as previously selected nothing is changed. And because removing the field text does not trigger the underlying `js` value widget still thinks the date is there.
You can verify it by changing the date by hand and then clicking the calendar icon - marked date is not changed to the new one.

So answering your question:
If previously there was no value you can select today's date without a problem, only if the today's value was there and it was deleted by hand selecting today does not make it reappear.